# ASP.Net LinkButton opens page page x.asp when i click on linkButton xyz to open a new window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net web form page with LinkButton like Comment | Email | Download | Print.

I open Comment (Comment.asx) and Email (EmailArticle.aspx) Form in Ajax Modal Popup using jQuery. Everything works fine except when i click on **Print** LinkButton it opens the page as new window but on the main page it also moves from PageXYZ.aspx to EmailArticle.aspx page.

I am not sure what is wrong with the code i have check i could find anything wrong do i have to set some property so that when i Click on Download or Print it opens news windows but keeps the mail page same

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //Load EMail Form
        $("#<%=pnlEmailArticleForm.ClientID %>").load("EmailArticle.aspx", function () {
        //alert("Email Form has been loaded successfully!")
        });

         //For printing
         function CallPrint() {
             window.open('PrintArticle.aspx?articleID=<%=Request["articleID"] %>', 'Email', 'width=690, height=650,left=100, top=100, location=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=no, status=no, toolbar=no,fullscreen=no');
         }
    </script>
```

**HTML Code for Ajax Modal Popup**

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpShowCommentPopUp" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkBtnComment" PopupControlID="pnlComment"
 BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="imgBtnClose" RepositionMode="None"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

     <asp:Panel ID="pnlComment" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="490px" Width="520px" style="display:none">
         <div id="commentForm" class="commentForm">
            <div id="divClose" class="commentClose">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnClose" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/close.png" onclick="imgBtnClose_Click" CausesValidation="False"  />
            </div>
            <!-- comment Form -->
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlCommentForm" runat="server" Visible="true">

            </asp:Panel>
            <!-- comment Form -->
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>

<div>
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpShowEmailArticlePopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkBtnEmail" PopupControlID="pnlEmailArticle"
     BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="imgBtnCloseEmailPopup" RepositionMode="None"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
          <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailArticle" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="450px" Width="520px" >
             <div id="emailArticle" class="EmailArticleForm">
                 <div id="closeEmailArticle" class="commentClose">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnCloseEmailPopup" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/close.png" onclick="imgBtnCloseEmailPopup_Click" CausesValidation="False"  /> 
                 </div>
                 <!-- Email Form -->
                 <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailArticleForm" runat="server" Visible="true">

                 </asp:Panel>
                 <!-- Email Form -->
                 </div>
        </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

**Link Button Code in HTML**

```
   <!-- Article Details Section footer -->
    <div id="divArticleDetailsFooter"  class="divArticleDetailsFooter">
    <div id="divlblComment" class="imgTArticleDetailsFooter">
    <asp:Image ID="imgComment" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/comment.png"  />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnComment" runat="server" onclick="lnkBtnComment_Click" 
CssClass="divArticleDetailsFooterLabels" CausesValidation="False" >Comment</asp:LinkButton>

    </div>
<div id="divlblEmail" class="imgTArticleDetailsFooter">
<asp:Image ID="imgEmail" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/email.png" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnEmail" runat="server" 
CssClass="divArticleDetailsFooterLabels" CausesValidation="False" >Email</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
<div id="divlblDownload" class="imgTArticleDetailsFooter">
<asp:Image ID="imgDownload" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/download.png" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnDownload" runat="server" 
CssClass="divArticleDetailsFooterLabels" CausesValidation="False" >Download</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
<div id="divlblPrint" class="imgTArticleDetailsFooter">
<asp:Image ID="imgPrint" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/print.png" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnPrint" runat="server" OnClientClick="CallPrint()" 
CssClass="divArticleDetailsFooterLabels" CausesValidation="False" >Print</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
</div>  
<!-- Article Details Section footer -->
```

**Code behind Code**

```
protected void lnkBtnComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.mpShowCommentPopUp.Show();
}
protected void imgBtnClose_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.mpShowCommentPopUp.Hide();
}
protected void imgBtnCloseEmailPopup_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.mpShowEmailArticlePopup.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement `return false;` should be used to prevent the default behavior of elements such as anchors (links). When you have onclick defined on an A tag that also has href attribute, the browser will proceed with executing the href part if the onclick code does not specifically return false.

So, my guess is that your onclick handlers start a postback (since they are LinkButtons), which could be executing its onclick event at the server, which is designed to redirect to that other page (or some other code that normally executes, which you can find out by stepping through).

So, try that: add `return false` to your `CallPrint`.